# Ansible with_items refer to different list

Tags: ansible-2.x

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

I have the following task:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f33615218086b9a0512

following variables:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/42c4a0f46871e36c4761

I would like in first case item[0] to loop first list,
and with item[1] to loop over the second list.

Thanks,

Comment: here is the debug:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0667f548c4d9b36fd758

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a [nested loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops)

Using with_items, as you have it now, will just combine the lists and iterate over each item sequentially.  As you can see in your debug outputm item[0] and item[1](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops) are just the first and second characters in current loop item string